# Finitely generated ideals of integer valued polynomials

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb{Z}):= \{f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \mid f(\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}\}$. Any element of the integer valued polynomials can be written as a $\mathbb{Z}$ linear combination of the polynomials of the form $f_n(x) = x(x-1)...(x-n+1)/n!$. As a consequence, we can show that $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$- module.

Now I am stuck at a self-check that every finitely generated ideal of $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb{Z})$ is invertible. I have tried to compute the explicit inverse ideal of $I = \langle f_1,...,f_n\rangle$ but have not succeeded. My idea in a nutshell was to first prove it for an ideal of the form of $I$, then do it for any integral linear combinations, but have failed. If you could provide me with some hints and suggestions I would be highly obliged.

Comment: What do you mean, invertible/inverse ideal?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews They might be referring to this? Not sure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal

Comment: A fractional ideal $I$ of $R$ is invertible if there is a $J$ such that $IJ= R$

Comment: In fact, you want to prove that $\mathrm{Int}(\mathbb Z)$ is Prufer. See here:  https://math.mit.edu/~fgotti/docs/Courses/Ideal%20Theory/18.%20Rings%20of%20Integer-Valued%20Polynomials%20II/Integer-Valued%20Polynomials%20II.pdf

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the reference.